# Can't access array outside loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am experiencing a strange bug when accessing an array after being populated from another array within a for loop. CustomerName is passed from another area of code and holds the correct value. I can alert the new array within the first for loop, however no such luck within the second for loop. I receive an undefined error.

```
var aLocalDogs = new Array();
for (var a=0; a < localDogs.length; a++) {  
    if(CustomerName === localDogs[a].CustomerName){
        aLocalDogs[a]=localDogs[a];
        alert(aLocalDogs[a].CustomerName);
        alert(aLocalDogs[a].CustomerAddress);
   }
}
for (var b=0; b < aLocalDogs.length; b++) { 
    alert(aLocalDogs[b].CustomerName);
    alert(aLocalDogs[b].CustomerName);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Is this your actual code, or is there something in between?

Comment: the code is in between more code. localDogs holds values such as localDogs[1].DogTitle, localDogs[2].DogTitle and so on....

Comment: Please post a complete code example where we can reproduce the issue. Using a site like jsFiddle.net is usually helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that `localDogs[a].CustomerName` is not equal to `CustomerName` until `a == 5`. You then do:

`aLocalDogs[5] = localDogs[5];`

In your second loop, you try to access `alocalDogs[0]`. You never assigned to it.

Try using `aLocalDogs.push(localDogs[a])` instead:

```
var aLocalDogs = new Array();
for (var a=0; a < localDogs.length; a++) {  
    if(CustomerName === localDogs[a].CustomerName){
        aLocalDogs.push(localDogs[a]);
    }
}
```

Because `alocalDogs` has now been assigned to sequentially, the alerts in the first `for` loop will no longer work - but I assume these were for debugging anyway (otherwise you can just alert values of `localDogs[a]`). The second loop should now work.

Comment: Figured it out to come back and see the same solution you have put forward. Such a silly mistake.... Will mark as answer, thanks for your time...